# Unable to copy multiple cells from excel using poi

Tags: java, excel, apache-poi

There is an excel file with a single sheet with the following contents:

```
Date |Task |Hrs
-----|-----|---
Date1 | Task1 | 2
----- | ----- | -
Date2 | Task2 | 2
```

I need to create another sheet and copy the contents of sheet1 to it.

The following is the code snippet:

```
FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(fileName);

        wb = WorkbookFactory.create(fis);

        Sheet shOld = wb.getSheet(srcSheetName);
        Sheet shNew = wb.createSheet("Sheet2");

        int rc = shOld.getLastRowNum();
        Row r = shOld.getRow(0);
        int cc = r.getLastCellNum();

        for(int i =0; i<=rc;i++){
            r = shOld.getRow(i);
            for(int j=0; j<cc;j++){
                String temp = r.getCell(j, org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Row.CREATE_NULL_AS_BLANK).getStringCellValue();

                shNew.createRow(i).createCell(j).setCellValue(temp);
                }
            FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(fileName);
            wb.write(fos);
```

After I run the program, I see that only the last column is copied to Sheet2. That is, sheet2 looks something like this:

```
     |      | Hrs
---- |----- |----
     |      | 2
-----|----- |----
     |      | 2
```

Comment: Here's some hint: use a debugger and oput some breakpoint in your loop. WHen you reach the breakpoint, use `wb.write` to get an excel file see what's happening step by step

Comment: Maybe `shNew.createRow(i)` creates a new row each time (and overwrite previous content)

Comment: @RC is right, you should only create a row once, use getRow / store it for the cells